# Lie Ideal generated by one element

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V=(x)$ be the 1-dimensional vector subspace of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ generated by $x$. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ is the smallest Lie ideal containing $V$.  Is     $[\mathfrak{h}^n, \mathfrak{h}^m]= \mathfrak{h}^{n+m}$     ??

Recall that, the Lie ideal $\mathfrak{a}^n$ is defined inductively:

\begin{align}
\mathfrak{a}^n &= 
  \begin{cases}
      \,\, \mathfrak{a} & \text{if $\quad$ } n=1,\\
     \,\,[\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{a}^{n-1}] & \text{if $\quad$  } n>1,
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Why would this be true?

Comment: We always have $[h^n,h^m]\subset h^{n+m}$, and equality holds if $\min(n,m)=1$. So the first counterexample should occur for $(n,m)=(2,2)$, and for the minimal-dimensional counterexamples, one has $[h^2,h^2]=0$, that is, $h^2$ abelian (= h metabelian) but $h^4\neq 0$. David Towers yields such an example (with the additional little constraint that $h$ is generated by a single element as an ideal).

Answer (score 3):

No. Let L be the 5-dimensional Lie algebra over a field F with basis e1,e2,e3,e4,e5 and non-zero products [e2, e3] = e1, [e1, e4] = e1, [e2, e4] = e2, [e3, e5] = e3, [e2, e5] = −e2 and let x = e5. Then h = Fe1 + Fe2 + Fe3 + Fe5, h^2 = Fe1 + Fe2 + Fe3, [h^2,h^2] = Fe1, but h^n = h^2 for all n > 1.